# Differences in regex patterns between JavaScript and Java?

Tags: java, javascript, regex

In JavaScript, I have the following:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
    var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

It replaces all of the URLs in the input string with a version of the URL that has an anchor tag wrapped around it to turn it into a link. I'm trying to duplicate this functionality in Java with the following function:

```
private String replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(String text) {
    String pattern = "/(\\b(https?|ftp|file):\\/\\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|])/i";
    return text.replaceAll(pattern, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
}
```

However, while it works fine in JavaScript it doesn't find any matches in Java, even for the same input string. Do I need to change something in the pattern, or what's going on?

Comment: Sorry for offtopic, but using regex for parsing HTML tags is unsafe and emm.. ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get rid of the slashes around the expression and the `i` at the end for the Java example. You can specify the `i` flag separately. So JavaScript's `/blarg/i` would be turned into `"(?i)blarg"`.

Your code would become something like:

```
private String replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(String text) {
  String pattern = "(?i)(\\b(https?|ftp|file):\\/\\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|])";
  return text.replaceAll(pattern, "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is normal: Java's `Pattern` does not work this way.

Your regex is compatible with both engines, however you do not specify modifiers this way with Java.

Do:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(https?|ftp|file):\\/\\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%=~_|])", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
retrun pattern.matcher(text).replaceAll("<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
```