# JavaScript and Java regular expressions same?

Tags: javascript, regex

Are javascript and java regular expression the same?
Can we use the same regular expression at both places to validate both on server side client?

Comment: Regex is regex. Should work the same way. :)

Comment: can you share some scenarios so that we can give hints. its too broad to answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences in regex patterns between JavaScript and Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8629039/differences-in-regex-patterns-between-javascript-and-java)

Answer (score 1):

> Is javascript and java regular expression are same ?

They're very similar, but they're not the same, as a brief glance at reference material makes clear, say MDN's [article on JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions) vs. Java's [`Pattern` class documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). For one thing, Java's regex supports various Posix character classes which JavaScript regrettably does not.

> Can we use same regular expression at both place to validate server side validation and client side validation ????

That's actually a different question, because you can run JavaScript on the JVM, so you can use the exact same expression in your client-side JavaScript code and your server-side code running on the JVM, using Rhino or Nashorn, which are JavaScript scripting engines for the JVM. You can compile JavaScript code to Java bytecode and use it like a Java class.