# Regex.matches behave differently in Kotlin/JS

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to write a multiplatform library for comparing [SemVer](https://semver.org/) versions. I extracted the regular expression provided by the website to validate the *pre-release* part:

```kotlin
val preReleasePattern = Regex("""(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*""")
```

If I execute the following function in JVM and native, it return `true`. However, if I execute this statement in Nodejs, it returns `false`.

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val preReleasePattern = Regex("""(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*""")
    println(preReleasePattern matches "01s")
}
```

I am using Kotlin 1.6.0 and the `Regex` class is coming from `kotlin.text` package. Is my pattern incorrect or I have to write a different regular expression dedicated for JS environment?

Comment: Just tested it and it works on nodejs (versions 4 to 18). You should also post your JS code (Side note: there have been differences in RegEx between JVM and JS, but not in recent versions).

Comment: You might want to check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35571192/14575901) on StackOverflow. The engines of JS and JVM differ in the way they handle stuff. Your Kotlin code just gets **compiled/transformed** to JS code, so I think this behavior is normal. The Kotlin compiler cannot just infer what you want to accomplish in the JVM and sort of transpile it to JS.

Comment: I know the Regex syntax may different between Kotlin/Java and JavaScript, but it should be the duty of Kotlin compiler to convert it to JS version as the `Regex` class is provided by Kotlin Standard Library. Perhaps it is due to this bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-49065

Comment: you can use Kotlin/Wasm compile Regex to wasm, then use js load wasm. here is my demo [gkd-kit/gkd](https://github.com/gkd-kit/gkd/blob/main/wasm_matches/src/commonMain/kotlin/li/songe/matches/toMatches.kt) and [gkd-kit/inspect](https://github.com/gkd-kit/inspect/blob/748de1cefb71219d0abf4ac0c8e407213b551534/src/utils/selector.ts#L15)